# How to share a link to a picture in BTsync?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, bittorrent-sync

I have often files which I sync between my devices in BTsync. 
However, sometimes, I would like to share one picture or one video to one user elsewhere from the BTsync network. 
Technically, the hosting of file by computer should be possible, since I have many devices in the network with continuous mobile hosting.

It would be nice to get sharing features such as that you can decide how long the sharing is accessible by the link, similar to Dropbox.

I contacted the support of BTsync about the feature already

> There is no such an option as to share
>   only files, but we'll consider about adding it in future. However you
>   can copy the file to another folder, add it in the Sync and share it
>   with another people. If they don't have Sync it will be suggested to
>   install it.  Also you can choose link expiration days and/or how many
>   times it can be used.

---

How can you share one picture with a link to a picture in BTsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you'd share would be presumably HTTP or FTP, this isnt part of what BTSync does (and is a downside to it vs the likes of Dropbox in terms of convenience).

You would need to configure a webserver/FTP server on one of your computers and expose it on the appropriate port. You could then copy files into a "public" directory in your BTSync directory and then be able to link to them.

Comment: Your answer proposes me that webserver/FTP server should be bound in the BTsync such that the sharing is possible in the future.

Comment: I received an answer from BTsync support. They are going to include the feature later in BTsync. We just need to wait for a while now.